# Mist does not start anymore? Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ipc

Most recently, I get the following error after executing mist:

```
CONNECT to IPC PATH: /home/santi/.ethereum/geth.ipc
CONNECT to IPC PATH: /home/santi/.ethereum/geth.ipc
NODECONNECTOR ERROR { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
/home/santi/.ethereum/geth.ipc]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/home/santi/.ethereum/geth.ipc' }
Node type:  geth
Network:  main
Start node from /usr/share/mist/resources/node/geth/geth
Stopping nodes...
Starting geth node...
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION { [Error: spawn EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno:
'EACCES', syscall: 'spawn' }
Stopping nodes...
```

In my laptop works just executing mist without the need of executing
geth first... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible causes are `permission` or the `port` availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Executable flag

You have to make the node executable, so mist can run it. Try:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/mist/resources/node/geth/geth
```

#### Run geth manually

You can also install an run geth manually and after that running mist will allow mist to connect to the running geth instance.

```
geth --ipcpath=~/.ethereum/geth.ipc
```

If you don't know how to install geth on your system, you could simply symlink it to your `$PATH`, like:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/mist/resources/node/geth/geth 
sudo ln -s /usr/share/mist/resources/node/geth/geth /usr/bin/geth
```

This allows you to execute `geth` directly. Also see [this discussion for using system wide geht installation first](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/264).

Answer (score 0):

Mist opens only with geth running on the background

Comment: I think qwe was trying to say that the error was caused by geth not running in the background while mist is open. However, it should be worded a lot better.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I had to set exec rights on geth. Execute this once and try again:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/share/mist/resources/node/geth/geth`

Comment: Why does that get downvoted? It's a simple but correct answer.